# Get content of files with same name in subfolders to obtain a JSON array

Tags: json, sensors

I have the files in folders that begin with `28-`.

They are one wire bus sensors to measure the temperature. The Raspberry recognize them via its SPI interface; every probe has its ID (something beginning with 28-), and RB creates a tree for every sensor named as the probe's ID, like

```
ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1 -1
28-00000cbece94/
28-00000cbeeca3/
28-00000cbeedf6/
28-00000cbf87ba/
...
```

Inside the folder there are two files (among many others) which are `temperature` and `name`.

`name` is the probe ID which is also the folder name; `temperature` is ( ... surprise) the temperature.

Where the ID is both the folder name and the content of the file:

```
cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/28-00000cc002fa/name 
28-00000cc002fa
```

and the temp is

```
cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/28-00000cc002fa/temperature 
21812
```

I would like to write a script or compose a sequence of bash commands that ends in yielding an array of JSON objects, like:
`[ {"ID": "28-00000cbece94", "temp": 24.712}, {"ID": "28-00000cbeeca3", "temp": 24.735}, <so on> ]`
I think awk should be involved but maybe find -exec, but a simple grep+cat but even tree, but...

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only `jq` (twice) and a shell loop:

```bsh
for pathname in /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/28-*/; do
    jq -n \
        --arg ID "$(basename "$pathname")" \
        --arg temp "$(cat "$pathname"/temperature)" \
        '{ ID: $ID, temp: $temp }'
done |
jq -s '. | map( .temp = (.temp | tonumber / 1000) )'
```

The loop iterates over the pathnames corresponding to the directories that  starts with `28-` that you mentioned in the question.  The loop uses `jq` to create a single JSON object for each directory, consisting of an `ID` element and a `temp` element.  The value for `ID` will simply be the basename of the directory pathname, and the temperature is read from the `temperature` file in the directory.

These separate JSON objects are then piped to a second `jq` process which creates an array of them using the `-s` (`--slurp`) option.  It also modifies the `temp` element of each object by converting it from a string into a number and dividing it by 1000 (this is something you never said anything about, so I'm guessing).

The same thing, but using the slightly handier `jo` utility inside the loop:

```bsh
for pathname in /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/28-*/; do
    jo  ID="$(basename "$pathname")" \
        temp="$(cat "$pathname"/temperature)"
done |
jq -s '. | map( .temp /= 1000 )'
```

The `jo` utility additionally detects that `temp` is a number, so we don't have to convert these from strings later.

Both of these loops would create "pretty-printed" JSON like

```json
[
  {
    "ID": "28-00000cbece90",
    "temp": 21.812
  },
  {
    "ID": "28-00000cbece91",
    "temp": 21.812
  }
]
```

Add the `-c` (`--compact-output`) option to the final `jq` to instead produce compact output like

```json
[{"ID":"28-00000cbece90","temp":21.812},{"ID":"28-00000cbece91","temp":21.812}]
```

Comment: Great! It worked out of the box on the first trial: thanks!

Comment: @FedericoMunerotto Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.